# Docker won't regenerate most files in fastpages but it will regenerate index.html files

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I am running docker using WSL2 on windows 11 and I have WSL and Ubuntu integration applied. My server runs fine but for some reason when I save changes from certain files in _posts and _pages they will not upload to my server whereas when I save changes from index.html it uploads perfectly fine. There is no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by moving project to linux directory.